# Cprogram will not print nodes in linked list

Tags: c, parsing, linked-list

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I am simply trying to add a course node to a linked list with specified values, but when I attempt to print the linked list it keeps saying it is empty, I am not sure what is wrong.

I have everything working now, except that the list segfaults when I get about 1/3rd of the way through the list, and I do not know why. PLEASE HELP!

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<ctype.h>

 #define MAX 50

 typedef struct courses{
    char *abbr;
    char *name;
    int credits;
    char *prof;
    struct courses *next;
 }courses;

 int isAbbr(char *string);
 int isName(char *string);
 int isCredit(char *string);
 int isProf(char *string);
 int isPre(char *string);
 courses *readfile(FILE *);
 courses *create_course(char *abbr, char *prof, int credits, char *fulldesc);
 courses *create_list(courses *, courses *);
 void Print(courses *);

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
            printf("Inadequate amount of arguments.\n");
            return 0;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
            printf("File cannot be opened.\n");
            return 0;
    }

    courses* head = NULL;
    head = readfile(fp);

    Print(head);

    printf("=== task1: construct a linear linked list from the catalog ===\n\n=== task2: user input and producing output ===\n\n");
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 3)
    {
            printf("\nSelect your option below:\n1-Register for a Course\n2-See my total\n3-Exit\nChoice: ");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
 }

 courses *readfile(FILE *fp)
 {
    courses *head, *entry;
    head = entry = NULL;

    char *abbr = malloc(MAX);
    char *name = malloc(MAX);
    char *prof = malloc(MAX);
    char *desc = malloc(MAX);
    char *fulldesc = malloc(MAX);
    char *fullName = malloc(MAX);

    int credit;
    int credflag = 0;
    int nameFlag = 0;
    int profFlag = 0;
    int preFlag = 0;
    int credits = 0;
    int descflag = 0;

    char line[MAX];
    while (fgets(line, MAX - 1, fp) != NULL)
    {
            if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n')
            {
                    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
            }
            char* token = strtok(line," ,\t");
            while (token != NULL)
            {
                    if (isAbbr(token) == 1)
                    {
                            abbr = malloc(sizeof(char));;
                            strcpy(abbr, token);
                            credflag = 1;
                            preFlag = 0;
                            profFlag = 1;
                    }
                    if (isName(token) == 1)
                    {
                            if (descflag == 1 && isCredit(token) != 1)
                            {
                                    fulldesc = strcat(desc, token);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    desc = malloc(sizeof(char));
                                    strcpy(desc,token);
                                    descflag = 1;
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            descflag = 0;
                    }
                    if (isCredit(token) == 1 && credflag == 1)
                    {
                                    credits = atoi(token);
                                    credflag = 0;
                                    descflag = 0;
                    }
                    if (isProf(token)== 1 && profFlag == 1)
                    {
                            if(nameFlag == 1 && name[0] != 'T' && token[0] != 'O') 
                            {
                                    prof = strcat(name, token);
                                    entry = create_course(abbr,prof,credits, fulldesc);
                                    head = create_list(head,entry);
                                    profFlag = 0;
                                    nameFlag = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    name = malloc(sizeof(char));
                                    strcpy(name, token);
                                    nameFlag = 1;
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            nameFlag = 0;
                    }
                    token = strtok(NULL," ,\t");
            }
    }
}

courses *create_course(char *abbr, char *prof, int credits, char *fulldesc)
 {
    courses *entry = (courses*)malloc(sizeof(courses));

    //printf("%30s %50s %30s %30d\n",abbr,fulldesc,prof,credits);

    entry->abbr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(entry->abbr, abbr);

    entry->prof=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(entry->prof, prof);

    entry->name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(entry->name, fulldesc);

    entry->credits = credits;
    entry->next = NULL;

    return entry;
 }

courses *create_list(courses *head, courses *entry)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
            return entry;
    }
    courses* curr = head;
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
            curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = entry;

    return head;
}

void Print(courses *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
            printf("Course list is empty\n\n");
            return;
    }
    printf("\n");
    while(head)
    {
            printf("%20s %20d\n",head->abbr,head->credits);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

 int isName(char *string)
 {
    int length = strlen(string);
    int i;
    if (isupper(string[0]))
    {
            for (i=1; i<length; i++)
            {
                    if (isupper(string[i]) || string[i] == ':')
                    {
                            continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            return 0;
                    }
            }
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
 }

int isPre(char *string)
{
    int length = strlen(string);
    int i;
    if (length == 14)
    {
            printf("\t%s\n",string);
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int isProf(char *string)
{
    int length = strlen(string);
    int i;
    if (isupper(string[0]))
    {
            for (i=1; i<length; i++)
            {
                    if (islower(string[i]))
                    {
                            continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            return 0;
                    }
            }
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int isCredit(char *string)
{
    int n;
    int nfields = sscanf(string, "%d", &n);
    if (nfields == 1)
    {
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

 int isAbbr(char *string)
 {
    int length = strlen(string);
    if (length == 8 && string[4] == '-')
    {
            //printf(" %s\n",string);
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: How about a little hint to where the problem may be...

Comment: Looks like comp-sci homework to me.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use a debugger like GDB. Finding a bug like this becomes trivial. Since this is a linked-list, I assume it is your first assignment for your course. Coming to StackOverflow and waiting for answers for every error you experience after this isn't going to work.

Every programmer needs to know how to use a debugger. You will not be able to get through school without one.